# What is the correct syntax to construct a class with a shared_ptr as member field?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Suppose, I want to make a class `B` with a pointer to another class `A`. In the constructor of `A` I want to construct `B` and passing it a pointer to `this`. In principle, this pointer can be a `shared_ptr`, correct? Then how do I make such a class with the assignment of the `shared_ptr` in the constructor?

I tried it in the code below. `ClassB` and `ClassC` are identical, with a pointer to `ClassA` which constructs instances of `ClassB` and `ClassC`. The only two differences are that `ClassB` holds a regular pointer and `ClassC` holds a `shared_ptr` to `ClassA` and that the code with `ClassB` is working and the code with `ClassC` is not. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Main.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "ClassA.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Create B and C separately, without a reference to A:" << std::endl;
    ClassB(nullptr);
    ClassC(nullptr);

    std::cout << "Create A, and through it B and C:" << std::endl;
    ClassA A;

    A.PrintHello();
    A.getObjectB().getPointerToA()->PrintHello();

    A.PrintHello();
    A.getObjectC().getPointerToA()->PrintHello();
    return 0;
}

// ClassA.h

#pragma once

#include "ClassB.h"
#include "ClassC.h"

class ClassA
{
private:
    ClassB objectB;
    ClassC objectC;

public:
    ClassA(void);

    ClassB getObjectB() { return objectB; };
    ClassC getObjectC() { return objectC; };

    void PrintHello();
};

// ClassA.cpp

#include "ClassA.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

ClassA::ClassA(void) : objectB(ClassB( this )), objectC(ClassC( std::make_shared<ClassA>(*this) ))
{
    std::cout << "Class A fully constructed" << std::endl;
}

void ClassA::PrintHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

// ClassB.h

#pragma once

#include <memory>

class ClassA;

class ClassB
{
private:
    ClassA* pointerToA;

public:
    ClassB(ClassA* pA);

    ClassA* getPointerToA() { return pointerToA; };
};

// ClassB.cpp

#include "ClassB.h"
#include <iostream>

ClassB::ClassB(ClassA* pA) : pointerToA(pA)
{
    std::cout << "Class B constructed" << std::endl;
}

// ClassC.h

#pragma once

#include <memory>

class ClassA;

class ClassC
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<ClassA> pointerToA;

public:
    ClassC(std::shared_ptr<ClassA> pA);

    std::shared_ptr<ClassA> getPointerToA() { return pointerToA; };
};

// ClassC.cpp

#include "ClassC.h"
#include <iostream>

ClassC::ClassC(std::shared_ptr<ClassA> pA) : pointerToA(pA)
{
    std::cout << "Class C constructed" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not doing the same thing:

```
ClassA::ClassA(void) : objectB(ClassB( this )), objectC(ClassC( std::make_shared<ClassA>(*this) ))
```

The first initializer creates a temporary of type `ClassB` with the `this` pointer and initializes `objectB` by copying that temporary:

```
objectB(ClassB( this ))
```

The second creates a *new* `ClassA` as a copy of `*this`, stores it in a `shared_ptr`, then initializes a temporary `ClassC` with that `shared_ptr`, then initializes `objectC` by copying that temporary:

```
objectC(ClassC( std::make_shared<ClassA>(*this) ))
```

Your syntax is unnecessarily verbose, avoid the temporaries and copies and initialize your members directly:

```
    objectB( this ), objectC( std::make_shared<ClassA>(*this) )
```

This is equivalent to:

```
    objectB( this ), objectC( std::shared_ptr<ClassA>( new ClassA(*this) ) )
```

It should be clear that `objectB` has a pointer to `this` but `objectB` has a (shared) pointer to a *different* object, that is a copy of `*this`.

The point of a `shared_ptr` is it owns the pointer you give it, and will (generally) delete the pointer.  You can't have a `shared_ptr` that owns `this` in an object's constructor, because until the object has finished being constructed it can't be owned by any `shared_ptr` (the pointer you give to a `shared_ptr` is a pointer to a *complete* object, not a partially constructed one half way through it's constructor) so there's no safe way to get a `shared_ptr` referring to `this` that you can pass to `objectC`'s constructor.  There is a way to do it, using the aliasing feature of `shared_ptr` but I think you should re-examine your design and ask *why* you want `objectC` to "own" the object it's part of ... that doesn't make sense.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! I indeed don't want that objectC "owns" objectA, it is the other way around. I do want however that objectC knows its "owner", and therefore it needs some reference to objectA. Is it best practice then to use a general pointer for it?

Comment: @physicalattraction, yes, a simple pointer is fine if you don't need to own the thing it points to, and you know the pointer will always remain valid. In your case the parent object will always outlive its sub-objects, so it's safe for the sub-objects to store a `ClassA*` to their parent.

Answer (score 1):

`std::make_shared` allocates and initializes a new object.